# Find the limit of $\dfrac{e^{x^2}}{xe^x}$

Tags: limits

Please help me find this limit. I have already tried to use L'Hopitals rule and logarithmic differentiation but it turns into a quadratic.

Comment: Assuming limit to $\infty$?

Comment: Use $e^{x^2} / e^{x} = e^{x^2-x}$.

Answer (score 5):

If we choose to evaluate the limit using L'Hospital's Rule, then we can simply write

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{e^{x^2}}{xe^x}&=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{e^{x^2-x}}{x}\\\\
&=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{(2x-1)e^{x^2-x}}{1}\\\\
&=\infty
\end{align}$$

Alternatively we can use the inequality for the exponential

$$e^{z}\ge 1+z$$

Then, we have

$$\frac{e^{x^2-x}}{x}\ge \frac{1+x^2-x}x\to \infty \,\,\text{as}\,\,x\to \infty$$

and we are done!`

Comment: @LandonCarter Thank you! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I will assume you mean to evaluate the limit as $x\to\infty$.

Note, the expression is actually $\dfrac{e^{x^2-x}}{x}$. Now, we know for large $y$, the inequality $e^y\geq 1+y$ is true.

So noting that our expression is always non-negative, and putting $y=x^2-x$ in the above inequality, $\dfrac{e^{x^2-x}}{x}\geq \dfrac{1+x^2-x}{x}=\dfrac{1}{x}+x-1$.

As $x\to\infty$, the right side goes to $\infty$, so the limit is indeed $\infty$.

Comment: You are expanding $e^{x^2-x}$ at $x = 0$, that does not help to compute the limit for $x \to \infty$.

Comment: It doesn't really matter....the power series expansion for $e^x$ converges over the whole real line.

Comment: It does matter. The "H.O.T." like $x^3, x^4, ...$ cannot be ignored for $x \to  \infty$.

Comment: Okay, thanks for pointing out. Am fixing it.

Comment: Minor nitpick: $e^y\geq 1+y$ is true for *all* real numbers *y*, not only for large numbers.

Comment: Yes, but let's be in safe hands since we are interested in $x$ getting unbounded, for the time being. ;)